# how to give zoom Support feature for Angular 2 NVD3 Chart

Tags: angular, d3.js, nvd3.js, angular-nvd3, ng2-nvd3

I found some zoom functions for angular 1.x nvd3 chart. but I don't really know how to access them via the options in angular 2 nvd3 chart?

Based on the nvd3 website there's a zooming functionality – chart: { zoom: {} }, I've placed it in my ng2 component but does nothing to my scatter chart.

Would really appreciate all the help.
This is my piece of code

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.options = {
      chart: {
        type: 'historicalBarChart',
        height: 450,
        margin : {
            top: 20,
            right: 20,
            bottom: 65,
            left: 50
        },
        x: function(d){return d[0];},
        y: function(d){return d[1]/100000;},
        showValues: true,
        valueFormat: function(d){
            return d3.format(',.1f')(d);
        },
        duration: 100,
        xAxis: {
            axisLabel: 'X Axis',
            tickFormat: function(d) {
                return d3.time.format('%x')(new Date(d))
            },
            rotateLabels: 30,
            showMaxMin: false
        },
        yAxis: {
            axisLabel: 'Y Axis',
            axisLabelDistance: -10,
            tickFormat: function(d){
                return d3.format(',.1f')(d);
            }
        },
        tooltip: {
            keyFormatter: function(d) {
                return d3.time.format('%x')(new Date(d));
            }
        },
        zoom: {
            enabled: true,
            scaleExtent: [1, 10],
            useFixedDomain: false,
            useNiceScale: false,
            horizontalOff: false,
            verticalOff: true,
            unzoomEventType: 'dblclick.zoom'
        }
    }
    }
    this.data = [
      {
        "key" : "Quantity" ,
        "bar": true,
        "values" : [ [ 1136005200000 , 1271000.0] , [ 1138683600000 , 1271000.0] , [ 1141102800000 , 1271000.0] , [ 1143781200000 , 0] , [ 1146369600000 , 0] , [ 1149048000000 , 0] , [ 1151640000000 , 0] , [ 1154318400000 , 0] , [ 1156996800000 , 0] , [ 1159588800000 , 3899486.0] , [ 1162270800000 , 3899486.0] , [ 1164862800000 , 3899486.0] , [ 1167541200000 , 3564700.0] , [ 1170219600000 , 3564700.0] , [ 1172638800000 , 3564700.0] , [ 1175313600000 , 2648493.0] , [ 1177905600000 , 2648493.0] , [ 1180584000000 , 2648493.0] , [ 1183176000000 , 2522993.0] , [ 1185854400000 , 2522993.0] , [ 1188532800000 , 2522993.0] , [ 1191124800000 , 2906501.0] , [ 1193803200000 , 2906501.0] , [ 1196398800000 , 2906501.0] , [ 1199077200000 , 2206761.0] , [ 1201755600000 , 2206761.0] , [ 1204261200000 , 2206761.0] , [ 1206936000000 , 2287726.0] , [ 1209528000000 , 2287726.0] , [ 1212206400000 , 2287726.0] , [ 1214798400000 , 2732646.0] , [ 1217476800000 , 2732646.0] , [ 1220155200000 , 2732646.0] , [ 1222747200000 , 2599196.0] , [ 1225425600000 , 2599196.0] , [ 1228021200000 , 2599196.0] , [ 1230699600000 , 1924387.0] , [ 1233378000000 , 1924387.0] , [ 1235797200000 , 1924387.0] , [ 1238472000000 , 1756311.0] , [ 1241064000000 , 1756311.0] , [ 1243742400000 , 1756311.0] , [ 1246334400000 , 1743470.0] , [ 1249012800000 , 1743470.0] , [ 1251691200000 , 1743470.0] , [ 1254283200000 , 1519010.0] , [ 1256961600000 , 1519010.0] , [ 1259557200000 , 1519010.0] , [ 1262235600000 , 1591444.0] , [ 1264914000000 , 1591444.0] , [ 1267333200000 , 1591444.0] , [ 1270008000000 , 1543784.0] , [ 1272600000000 , 1543784.0] , [ 1275278400000 , 1543784.0] , [ 1277870400000 , 1309915.0] , [ 1280548800000 , 1309915.0] , [ 1283227200000 , 1309915.0] , [ 1285819200000 , 1331875.0] , [ 1288497600000 , 1331875.0] , [ 1291093200000 , 1331875.0] , [ 1293771600000 , 1331875.0] , [ 1296450000000 , 1154695.0] , [ 1298869200000 , 1154695.0] , [ 1301544000000 , 1194025.0] , [ 1304136000000 , 1194025.0] , [ 1306814400000 , 1194025.0] , [ 1309406400000 , 1194025.0] , [ 1312084800000 , 1194025.0] , [ 1314763200000 , 1244525.0] , [ 1317355200000 , 475000.0] , [ 1320033600000 , 475000.0] , [ 1322629200000 , 475000.0] , [ 1325307600000 , 690033.0] , [ 1327986000000 , 690033.0] , [ 1330491600000 , 690033.0] , [ 1333166400000 , 514733.0] , [ 1335758400000 , 514733.0]]
    }
    ];

  }
```

Comment: Did you find a way to do it eventually?

Comment: NO . I haven't. Any way is there?